# RewriteRule does not work in wampserver

Tags: php, .htaccess, wamp

Hello I would like to change the url generated with php my website. I've tried with .htaccess but does absolutely nothing, I do not know if I'm doing something wrong.

Right now I do not have to test server, I can only do so locally. I have installed WAMP but including the .htaccess file in the folder www does nothing, URLs continue with php variables as usual.

I have enabled mod_rewrite in wampserver. By including text meaningless in the .htaccess file fails to access by browser to localhost, that is I think the .htaccess is working.

Htaccess I have written in this way for me to rewrite the url:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /novedades/novedades.php?id=$1&url=$2&url=$3

#http://localhost/novedades/novedades.php?id=2&url=tren&url=tren

#http://localhost/novedades/tren/tren.php
```

I do not know if I'm doing something wrong, to see if I can lend a hand.

Comment: for allowing .htaccess you need to set `AllowOverride all` in your root .htaccess (or in your virtualhost file)

Comment: Just try a hosting and neither does anything, I think I have something wrong position in the htaccess. Let's see if someone can help me.
AllowOverride all I got on, I looked before.